# angularjs resource limit changes after first call

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

**Problem description**

Im using the angular resource to get data from my server. I've extended it a bit to make sure all of my resources have security headers.

Problem is that on the second get request and on, my get requests are sent with limit=0, and only the first get request is sent correctly (with limit=12).

**Code part**

This is my base resource factory (for making sure all resource contain the keys and everything):

```
app.factory('SecuredFactory', function($resource){   
    var DEFAULT_ACTIONS = {
      'get':    {method:'GET'},
      'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:true},
    };   
    var DEFAULT_PARAMS = {
        'limit': 12,
        'format': 'json'
    };  
    for(var key in DEFAULT_ACTIONS){
        DEFAULT_ACTIONS[key]['headers'] = <headers object>;
    }    
    var securedResource = function(url, paramDefaults, actions){
        for (var attrname in actions) { 
            DEFAULT_ACTIONS[attrname] = actions[attrname]; 
        }

        for (var attrname in paramDefaults) { 
            DEFAULT_PARAMS[attrname] = paramDefaults[attrname]; 
        }
        var defaultResource = $resource(url, DEFAULT_PARAMS, DEFAULT_ACTIONS);
        return defaultResource;
     };   
     return securedResource; 
});
```

And this is an example of how I creat a specific factory out of the secured one:

```
app.factory('QuestionFactory', function(SecuredFactory, Constants){   
    var url = Constants.SERVER_URL + 'question/';
    var Task = SecuredFactory(url);
    return Task;
});
```

And this is finally how I use it, for example:

```
// filtering example (not important for this matter):
var filtering = {author: "Daniel"};

var contents = [];
var resource = QuestionFactory;
resource.get(filtering, function (res) {
    // success fetching
    $scope.contents = $scope.contents.concat(res['objects']);
  }
  // failed fetching
  , function (err) {

  }
);
```

**The requests**

first request:

```
question?format=json&limit=12&offset=0
```

second request and on:

```
question?format=json&limit=0&offset=0
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug the for loops and see what is returned?

Comment: @MichelTomé - I know what is returned. I get all of the objects instead of just 12. And that is obviously happens because of the requests which has limit=0 instead of limit=12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that the DEFAULT_PARAMS variable was declared as global. I didn't realize that invoking the secured factory with {limit: 0} will override the global, therefore changing the limit to 0 for **ALL** of my resources.

Changing the securedFactory to a service and moving the "globals" into the returned function solved it. Had to add new ofcourse before every securedService call.